# Heat press for low density polyethylene sheets

Tags: materials, heat-treatment, polyethylene, manufacturing

I want to create a double layer sheet with custom internal channels (created with CAD or similar software) out of two low-density-polyethylene sheets, similar to those used as greenhouse cover.

Is that even possible with that material and if yes is a heat press the way to go?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: LDPE can be thermoformed. Not clear about the geometry you're talking about -- a photo or drawing of a cross section would make the question more meaningful. A process using a hot roller comes to mind also, but I'm not familiar with it

Comment: You mentioned CAD software so I must point out: You do realize the machining for the molds is going to cost thousands right? If so, carry on.

Comment: @PeteW imagine a flat panel made from two sheets, that contains a channel of custom shape through which water or air can be pumped and flow from the input to the output. Tubes made of hard plastic or metal (to serve as the input and output) should also be "welded" to the plastic sheets.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes I realize that. An easy a cheap way to make protopypes before creating the final molds would be useful though.

Comment: That would probably be 3D printing or hacking it out with a hot air gun on clay plugs. Probably with PET rather than LDPE for this stage. There are easily thermoformable plastic sheets like Kydex but that is still high temperature enough to manipulate without a press. But I ran into a plastic that becomes like soft rubber in just hot water. Not even boiling but I don't know its name. Used in occupational therapy for forming splints right on your hand. That's probably what you want.

Comment: There seems to be various names: splinting plastic.

Comment: @DKNguyen Thank you for the information but it needs to be LDPE since that is what is readily available to me. I will try the hot air gun and clay plug method for now.

Comment: Can it have a uniform cross section? Then maybe produced by a rolling process ???  also how big, how much anticipated, etc etc

Comment: Make sure you get a clay temperature sufficiently higher than the LDPE. Or maybe a soft clay bed and clamped sheet where you can heatgun small areas and press metal rods and other easily purchased stock shapes to locally form your features. But if the entire sheet isn't warm might mess with tensioning the sheet. With the right clay it will remain hard and supportive elsewhere but be soft where you heat the plastic so you can press shapes down.

Comment: @PeteW No the cross section cannot be uniform. The dimensions (of the entire panel) should be around 1.5 m x 0.5 m with channels around 5-10 cm wide.

Comment: good... editing the question to include all this info would probably be helpful.  sounds like there's definitely potential for individual (vs continuous process) vacuum-formed part. wouldn't make sense unless quantity is such that you're prepared to spend many $ thousands for NRE cost, however. how you bond the upper and lower pieces would be a separate question.

Comment: What kind of tooling do you have? Do you have, oven, hydraulic press, woodworking tools, metalworking tools? Have you tried in a smaller scale? Smaller scale helps you to understand the challenges better. What kind of budget do you have?